# How to skip venv when committing using VScode

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

I am new to VScode and Git. I cloned a repo from Github using Git extension, created a virtual env on my own PC and ran it. But when I want to commit my changes, my source control also include files for venv. I wonder how can I skip them?

It's like:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mV6AO.png)

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to commit certain files to a github repo?
If that's the question, simply create a file called .gitignore at the root level of your project and write each filename (directories names etc) on a seperate line.
Now github will ignore those files, so they wont be committed.

Comment: or directory names, or wildcards, or wildcards in directories